# PHP - if I got $x = 244 i want to find 200; if I got $x = 677 I want to find 600.. where x is dynamic?

Tags: php

Given varibale `$x` where `$x` is dynamic int.
How can I find the following value in PHP?

```
ex: $x = 233; From 233 I want to find 200;
    $x = 498; From 498 I want to find 400;
```

Comment: So you want to round down the value to the nearest factor of 100?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Comment: @elssar not the nearest one then 498 will give 500 while I need 400. Should be less then the given number

Comment: @reverbnation, yes thats why I said round down.

Comment: just curious, does 1498 round to 1400 or 1000 ??

Comment: @Andrew : Right. Now for 1498 ?

Comment: Just a pity that round() doesn't have PHP_ROUND_UP/PHP_ROUND_DOWN options.... methinks that might be a nice low-hanging fruit option for a contribution to PHP core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is rounding down, I assume. PHP has a function for that, called [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php):

```
echo floor(4.3);   // 4
echo floor(9.999); // 9
```

That basically rounds down the fraction. Now, to round down integers, you'll need to do some more math:

```
$v=233;
$base=100;
$v_min=$base*(floor($v/$base));
```

Comment: Note that if you have a negative number, `floor` rounds "up"; `floor(-4.6)=-5`. And if you want to "round to nearest " with positive numbers only you may want to add 0.5 after dividing and before taking the `floor()`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo pow(10, strlen($x) - 1) * (floor($v/pow(10, strlen($x) - 1)));
```

Comment: Can you give an explanation as to why this code would work and what this code actually does? cheers

Comment: Seems to me `strlen` is used as a poor man's logarithm to get the scale of the number... Which works as long as the input is an unsigned integer.